# OpenGL Problems with Rendering Multiple Objects

Tags: c++, opengl, render

I'm brand new to OpenGL and am having some difficulty rendering multiple objects.

I have a vector each of which has its own VertexBuffer. Then, in the while loop I draw each shape on its own.

It's all well and good when I have many of the same objects (multiple cubes etc.) however, when I add a triangle mesh everything gets all out of whack.

I can have many cubes

[image]

I can have a single triangle mesh:

[image]

But, when I try to have a cube and then a triangle mesh I get:

[image]

I'm totally at a loss for what's going on. The code for my loop is provided below.

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

        // Get the size of the window
        int width, height;
        glfwGetWindowSize(window, &width, &height);

        float aspect_ratio = 1 * float(height)/float(width); // corresponds to the necessary width scaling

        double xpos, ypos;
        glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);

        // Clear the framebuffer
        glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Enable depth test
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        glUniform3f(program.uniform("triangleColor"), 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(program.uniform("proj"), 1, GL_FALSE, projection.data());
        glUniformMatrix4fv(program.uniform("view"), 1, GL_FALSE, view.data());

        int tally = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < surfaces.size(); i++) {

        Surface *s = surfaces[i];

        Vector3f color = s->getColor();

        int tempIndex = triangleIndex;
        Matrix4f model = s->getModel();

        // Convert screen position to world coordinates
        double xworld = ((xpos/double(width))*2)-1;
        double yworld = (((height-1-ypos)/double(height))*2)-1; // NOTE: y axis is flipped in glfw

        if (isPressed && mode == "translate") { 
            if(tempIndex == i) {
                Vector4f center = s->getCenter() + model.col(3);
                Vector4f displacement = Vector4f(xworld, yworld, 0, 1) - center;
                Matrix4f translation = translateMatrix(displacement(0), displacement(1), displacement(2));
                model = translation * s->getModel();
                s->setModel(model);
            }
        }
        glUniform3f(program.uniform("triangleColor"), color(0), color(1), color(2));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(program.uniform("model"), 1, GL_FALSE, model.data()); 
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, s->getVertices().size());
    }
```

And I initialize each VBO when making the object as

```
VertexBufferObject VBO;
VBO.init();
VBO.update(Vertices);
program.bindVertexAttribArray("position", VBO);

Surface* s = new Surface(VBO, Vertices, percentScale, 0, transformedCenter, SmoothNormals, FlatNormals, color);
s->setModel(model);
surfaces.push_back(s);
```

And where Program::bindVertexAttribArray is defined as

```
GLint Program::bindVertexAttribArray(
        const std::string &name, VertexBufferObject& VBO) const
{
  GLint id = attrib(name);
  if (id < 0)
    return id;
  if (VBO.id == 0)
  {
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(id);
    return id;
  }
  VBO.bind();
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(id);
  glVertexAttribPointer(id, VBO.rows, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
  check_gl_error();

  return id;
}
```

Comment: You don't show how you initialize your vertex buffer. I suspect that the buffer has the data of one model and then you are trying to render it with the element count of another. Btw, you are generating vertex buffers on the fly. This is not how this is supposed to be done. Create a VAO for each model and bind the correct buffers with their data at the beginning of the program. Then, in the render loop, simply activate the VAO and draw it.

Comment: @NicoSchertier is there a way to switch between two shading models (flat vs. phong) without creating vertex buffers on the fly? I need two different sets of normals to use in the vertex shader and thought I needed to create VBOs as I went.

Comment: @NicoSchertier I think you're right because there's also a problem of it drawing 2 objects the opposite color. Why though would there be this switcheroo?

Comment: If you want different normal sets, you can have two VAOs that reference two different normal VBOs.

Comment: This is almost unclear. What does `bindVertexAttribArray`, `VBO_C.init` and `VBO_C.update` do? Where are the vertex coordinates. Do you miss to change the vertex coordinates. Do you use a [vertex array object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object)? You have to add more information, to make this a [Minimal, **Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the other VBOs. I have a feeling that the for loop is mixing up which element I'm on even though it knows which surface it's working on.

Comment: Similarly, when I make a cube, then a mesh, then another cube it turns the mesh into a cube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not binding any buffers before the draw call. You're probably simply drawing whatever buffer you last bound when you initialised them. You'll need something like this at the end of your loop before `glDrawArrays`:

```
...
program.bindVertexAttribArray("position", VBO); // where VBO is the buffer of surface s
glUniform3f(program.uniform("triangleColor"), color(0), color(1), color(2));
glUniformMatrix4fv(program.uniform("model"), 1, GL_FALSE, model.data()); 
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, s->getVertices().size());
```

Comment: Wow. That totally worked. But that feels really inefficient. Is there a better way to do this where I bind the object only once but can manipulate its model, normals etc. ?

Comment: Yes, what Nico Schertler wrote in his comment: use a VAO per surface.